# Chrome-extension: Append functions to right click menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How would I append functions to the right click menu in the browser? E.g `something` appended to the right click menu which does function `dosomething()` which is located in my extension.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Found out how, using the contextmenu API https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/

Answer (score 64):

I made simple extenstion using the contextMenu API - [link](https://github.com/anurag-ks/SearchTool) 
 Hope this works well as an example.

manifest.json -

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
  ...
  "permissions": [
      "contextMenus", 
      "tabs"],
  ...
  ...
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }
}
```

main.js -

```
 searchUrbanDict = function(word){
    var query = word.selectionText;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + query});
 };

chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "Search in UrbanDictionary",
 contexts:["selection"],  // ContextType
 onclick: searchUrbanDict // A callback function
});
```

For more information on different context types - [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType)

Answer (score 9):

Anurag-Sharma's answer updated for manifest v3:

manifest.json -

```
{
    "name": "terapeak",
    "description": "easy way to research ebay products",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "main.js"
    }
}
```

main.js

```
searchTerapeak = function(word){
    var query = word.selectionText;
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.ebay.com/sh/research?dayRange=365&sorting=-avgsalesprice&tabName=SOLD&keywords="
+ query});  };

chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
     id: "1",
     title: "Terapeak this!",
     contexts:["selection"],  // ContextType
    }); })

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(searchTerapeak);
```

Why you need to removeAll each time: [Why does chrome.contextMenus create multiple entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190701/why-does-chrome-contextmenus-create-multiple-entries)