# Why does chrome.contextMenus create multiple entries?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I am using `chrome.contextMenus.create` function to create context menus in my Chrome extension. But it creates extra options.

I gave permission in my `manifest.json` file, added this function my `background.js` file and added it my `manifest.json` file.

Why this is happening ?

```
function getword(info,tab) {
  console.log("Word " + info.selectionText + " was clicked.");
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText,
  });           
}
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Search: %s", 
  contexts:["selection"], 
  onclick: getword,
});
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the actual code you use for creating parent-child context menus? And when did you call `chrome.contextMenus.create`? I guess you didn't wrap your function into something like `chrome.runtime.onStartup` event which causes the function will be called everytime extension is activated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your background code will execute multiple times - at least on each browser start / extension reload, and at most every time an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (`"persistent": false`) wakes up.

[`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) does what it says on a tin - creates a new entry. Every time it's run. Which would be fine, as normally you want to setup everything when your extension is run, but **context menu entries actually *persist* between extension reloads** - so they keep piling up.

There are two approaches here:

1. Assign an ID to your context entry (which is an arbitrary string); in this case, calling `create` again with the same ID will <del>overwrite it</del> raise an error, not create a new one.

   ```
   chrome.contextMenus.create({
     title: "Search: %s",
     id: "search",
     contexts:["selection"], 
     onclick: getword,
   });
   ```

   This is useful anyway to manipulate / refer to the entry later anyway.
2. Wipe your context menu entries before calling `create`:

   ```
   chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
     chrome.contextMenus.create({
       // ...
     });
   });
   ```

   This may seem superfluous, but it's the easiest way to ensure that "old" context menu entries from previous versions of your extension don't linger.

Of course, you can combine the two.

---

A couple further remarks:

- If you are actually using `"persistent": false` Event page, note that using `onclick` attribute is not allowed, as it will be invalidated by extension unload. A more robust way is to use `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` event - the ID of the menu item will be passed to it to distinguish between options.
- Since you very rarely need to update the context menu items, it's best to hide them away in corresponding events, [`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onStartup) and/or [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled).

  However, be aware that you open yourself to a bug in a very rare combination of circumstances:

  1. The extension is installed but disabled.
  2. An update happens while it is disabled.
  3. This update actually should change context menu in either of those events.
  4. Then, the extension is enabled again.

  In those circumstances, *neither* event will fire. This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=388231).

Comment: Dude thank you , i added  "chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function()" and "id", it is working properly now.